# method template overload in class template using sfinae

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, sfinae

I'm trying to create a template class with a template overloaded method using SFINAE to exclude the unused methods but after read many post and hours of work I can't figure out which is my error.

My idea is create a class template with 4 parameters, 3 of them are optionals, 2 of the optionals parameters will be used in a overloaded method and only the right versions will be compiled, something like this (sorry I try to use the syntax highlight but I don't know how)

```
template<char const q[], typename P1 = void, typename P2 = void, typename P3 = void>
class query
{
    char const * const value;
  public:
    query() : value(q) {};
    template<typename returnType, something else>
    returnType execute(P1 data1, P2 data2) { ..... };
    template<typename returnType, something else>
    returnType execute(P2 data2) { ..... };
    template<typename returnType, something else>
    returnType execute(P1 data1) { ..... };
    template<typename returnType, something else>
    returnType execute() { ..... };
}
constexpr char const q_str[] = "hola mundo";

class A {};
int main()
{
    query<q_str> v1;
    query<q_str, A> v2;

    A param;

    bool rc = v2.execute<bool>(param); << I expect to use the method execute(P1 data1)
    return 0;
}
```

So, my code is this

```
template<char const q[], typename Tin = void, typename Tout = void, typename Twhere = void>
class query
{
    char const * const value;
public:
    typedef Tin ty_bind_in;
    typedef Tout ty_bind_out;

    query() : value(q) {};

    template<typename returnType,
             typename in = Tin,
             typename cond = typename std::enable_if< std::is_class<in>::value, void >::type>
    returnType execute(Tin &p_data)
    {
        returnType rs;
        return rs;
    };

    template<typename returnType>
    returnType execute()
    {
        returnType rs;
        return rs;
    };
};

constexpr char const q_str[] = "hola mundo";

class A {};

int main()
{
    query<q_str, A> q1;
    query<q_str> q2;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using this version of gcc

```
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

My line to compile is this

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g stack.cpp
```

and I get this errors

```
stack.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class query<((const char*)(& q_str))>’:
stack.cpp:40:15:   required from here
stack.cpp:19:13: error: forming reference to void
  returnType execute(Tin &p_data)
             ^
```

As you can see, I get the errors as soon as I declare my variable. Probably I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out where is the problem.

**EDIT 14/09:** Hi again, after the explanation of Barry I solve this problem and continue with my idea, so I try to add two more overload for method execute, the first one is this (Idea: this method will work when template parameters Tin and Twhere will be != void)

```
template<typename returnType,
         typename in = Tin,
         typename cond2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<in>::value >::type, 
         typename where = Twhere,
         typename cond = typename std::enable_if< std::is_class<where>::value >::type>
returnType execute(in &p_data, where &p_where)
{
    returnType rs;
    return rs;
};
```

And the second one is this (Idea: this method will work when template parameter Twhere will be != void)

```
template<typename returnType,
         typename where = Twhere,
         typename cond = typename std::enable_if< std::is_class<where>::value >::type>
returnType execute(where &p_data)
{
    returnType rs;
    return rs;
};
```

and I get the following error

```
stack.cpp:39:13: error: ‘template<const char* q, class Tin, class Tout, class Twhere> template<class returnType, class where, class cond> returnType query<q, Tin, Tout, Twhere>::execute(where&)’ cannot be overloaded
  returnType execute(where &p_data)
             ^
stack.cpp:19:13: error: with ‘template<const char* q, class Tin, class Tout, class Twhere> template<class returnType, class in, class cond> returnType query<q, Tin, Tout, Twhere>::execute(in&)’
  returnType execute(in &p_data)
```

In my opinion this is because the overloaded version for Tin and Twhere look equals in term of parameters but I don't know how to correct the code.

Some ideas?.

Thank you in advance
Best Regards

Comment: Is your first block of code relevant to the question? Do you mind if I simply remove it?

Comment: Hi Barry, my first block of code is just an example to show my intention, because my real code could have errors, in fact, probably have errors

Answer (score 3):

When you write this function:

```
template <....>
returnType execute(Tin &p_data)
```

if `Tin` is `void`, that is ill-formed. While that condition will always be excluded due to SFINAE, the function itself is still ill-formed and the compiler is allowed to error there. Instead, you should use your template parameter there:

```
template<typename returnType,
         typename in = Tin,
         typename cond = typename std::enable_if< std::is_class<in>::value, void >::type>
returnType execute(in& p_data)
                   ^^^^
```

---

Side-note, the extra `void` in your `enable_if` is unnecessary, as that is the default. If you have a C++14 compiler, you should prefer `std::enable_if_t`, and if you don't, you should write that alias somewhere just for usability. That would let you write:

```
template<typename returnType,
         typename in = Tin,
         typename = enable_if_t<std::is_class<in>::value>>
returnType execute(in& p_data)
```

way fewer characters, easier to grok the important parts.

Comment: Wow .... As usual your answer are excelent, very clear. Thank you very much!!! .. About the extra void, is true, is unnecesary but i put it because I need to be very explicit in my codes, you know my skills related to templates need a lot of work yet. Thank you again!!

Comment: @Trungus Explicit is great, but for `enable_if` - it's less important. Here, you're not using it for the `void` - you don't even care what the type is, you're just using it for the `enable_if` part. Excluding it just makes it easier for other people to see what it is you're doing.

Comment: I understand, I'll try to take into account ;) ... thank you for your help and your advice :D